# How to get AppBar menu working in react material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get the AppBar working with an IconMenu just like the example [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar), but the menu will not popup.
This is my code (exact copy of the example code):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/lib/icon-button';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/lib/menus/icon-menu';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

const AppBarExampleIconMenu = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
    iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
    iconElementRight={
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={
          <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
        }
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
      >
        <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
      </IconMenu>
    }
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(<AppBarExampleIconMenu />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

The AppBar shows up fine, but does not respond to clicking the menu-icon.
This is what shows up in google chrome's react plugin:

[image: screenshot of google chrome react plugin]

I guess the line with 'null' has something to do with the problem...?

(using material-ui 0.14.2, react 0.14.6)

Comment: Just found the solution, my bad: forgot to add react-tap-event-plugin. Sorry to have bothered you all...